# Swift 2 Mapkit Get City from user location

Tags: swift2, location, mapkit

Is it possible to get the name of the city and put that one into an array of strings from the user location, using Mapkit?
I already know how to get the user location so you dont have to go into that.

Comment: "Is it possible to get the name of the city and put that one into an array of strings from the user location" — what does that mean?

Comment: I want to get the name of the City , where the user is . For example the user is in Paris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can with using CLGeocoder class try to use this code

```
 CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinates.latitude, longitude: newCoordinates.longitude),             
     completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks![0]

                let c = pm.locality // city of place mark 

            }
            else {
                annotation.title = "Unknown Place"
                self.outletOfMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        })
```